# some problems with my eclipse when create an new project from existing android code

Tags: android, eclipse

the problem is ,when I want create an android project
by this stemp: *file->new->Project->android-android project from existing code->next* then Import Projects dialog opened, When I click Browse,the file browser points to the home folder in my case "administrator". 
Can I change this to make it point to my local drive C:\ for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your browser dialog you can choose the folder you want or type it directly in the file location bar ( located on the top )

Comment: when I want to chose workspace ,I an type it directly ,but when I want to create android project from existing code,I cannt do that.

Comment: I know ,I can type the folder directly ,then click refresh button，thank u